# Renaming VS2010 Build Configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I made a spelling mistake when creating a new build configuration.  I've corrected it using the Configuration manager but it hasn't corrected the name in all the projects in the solution as one would have naturally expected.  I also can;t see how to correct them individually, is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can edit the .sln and the .xxproj files with, say, notepad.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Configuration Manager
2. Select the Configuration drop-down in the list of projects
3. Select "Edit".  The Edit Project Configurations dialog will appear.
4. Select the misspelled configuration and click "Rename"